# Provider hierarchy in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am working on a toy application, which is an online shop application. I use `Provider` for state management. As it progresses, I notice patterns which are not easy to implement. I wanted to understand what is your take on it. I will explain the case.

There is a productsScreen which shows a list of products, it gets its list of products from a ProductsProvider. Right now it just fetches all the products from the server.

There is another widget which is MenuBarWidget. This widget hosts a few stuff including the search box. Like the ProductScreen it has a provider called MenuBarProvider. Now when user types in a search term in the search box int the MenuBarWidget, it updates the MenuBarProvider; then somehow the ProductsProvider has to see that change and adjust list of products accordingly. How do you do that? How two providers communicate ?

I know that it can be handled in the widgets, but that seems very ugly. Ideally I want to listen to MenuBarProvider from ProductsProvider; but I am not sure how to do that, and I am not even sure if that is such a great idea.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Personally when the state of the app that I must track becomes complex I create a bloc to save the state and then just fire events to update it, and I listen to the state in the widget, all this with the buisiness logic separated from **UI**. 

 https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tm-R7ymwhc

Answer (score 0):

to make 2 providers "communicate" with each other you should use the ProxyProvider.
It updates a provider when another provider updates.

ProxyProvider is part of the Provider package and it is meant exactly for this purpose, to provide dependency to Providers; see here for the docs:

https://pub.dev/packages/provider#proxyprovider

Check this article as well to see a full example:
https://dev.to/paulhalliday/how-to-use-proxyprovider-with-flutter-3ifo

You can use like this:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider(
      create: (_) => UserService(),
    ),
    ProxyProvider<UserService, GreetingService>(
      update: (BuildContext context, UserService userService,
              GreetingService greetingService) =>
          GreetingService(userService: userService),
    ),
  ],
 )
```

When UserService provider is updated, GreetingService will be updated as well so they will always be in sync.